# Mysql insert from another table based on mutual field

Tags: mysql

So theorycally I have table A with fields: id, name, code, ect... and table B simple as: code, name. The name field in table A is empty.

What I want to do is Inserting to table A.name From table B based on the code. So where the code is '111' in table A, I want the name to be the one that has the code '111' in table B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update a
inner join b on a.code = b.code
set name = b.name
```